# Class with vector of another class doesn't like to change its values

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a class called `intClass` that contains a private vector of `int`s and functions to modify its contents.  I have another class called `intClassClass` that contains a private vector of `intClass`es and functions to modify and print those.  When I attempt to change the innermost `int`s from the `intClassClass`, the function runs but the `int`s don't actually change.  I'm pretty sure the solution has something to do with a vector making a copy of the object instead of the object itself, but I'm not sure where that happens or how to fix it.

```
class intClass
{
private:
    vector<int> ints;
public:
    intClass()
    {
        ints.clear();
    }
    intClass(vector<int> iVec)
    {
        ints = iVec;
    }
    void modifyVec(int newInt, int index)
    {
        cout << "modified vec" << endl;

        ints[index] = newInt;
    }
    void printVec()
    {
        for (int i : ints)
        {
            cout << i << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    int getInt(int index)
    {
        return ints[index];
    }
};
class intClassClass
{
private:
    vector<intClass> ics;
public:
    intClassClass(vector<intClass> icVec)
    {
        ics = icVec;
    }
    intClass getIC(int index)
    {
        return ics[index];
    }
    void printVec()
    {
        for (intClass i : ics)
        {
            i.printVec();
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    intClassClass icc = intClassClass({ intClass({ 1,3,4,5,21 }), intClass({2, 4 }) });
    icc.printVec();
    icc.getIC(1).modifyVec(3, 0);
    icc.printVec();
    cout << icc.getIC(1).getInt(0);

    return 0;
}
```

this outputs
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uZ3y.png)

Comment: Use references (`intClass& getIC(...)`). In any case, `modifyVec()` and `getIC()` are a poor choice of method names; the idiomatic way to implement such functionality would be `int& operator [](size_t)` and `intClass& operator [](size_t)`, taking an index and returning a suitable reference. (Indices are `size_t`, not `int`, but that’s not too relevant here.)

Comment: `intClassClass(vector<intClass> icVec)` -- Pass vector's by const reference, not by value.  In general, it looks like you are not familiar with references, since there is no usage of them in your code.

Comment: The `getIC` function returns a *copy* of the object in the vector. You can modify this copy anyway you like, but it will not modify the original object inside the vector. Perhaps you should return a *reference* instead?

Comment: Objects in C++ have value semantics.  When you say `SomeType a = b;` you are making a new object whose value is equivalent to `b`.  `a` and `b` are not references to the same object as they would be in some languages like C# or Java.

Comment: `icc.getIC(1).modifyVec(3, 0);` will only have the effect you expect if `intClassClass::getIC()` returns a reference.  But it returns a value (which is a COPY of the member `ics`) and the copy is modified by the `modifyVec()` function. More generally (since people learning C++ very rarely make such an assumption otherwise) don't assume that C++ works the same as whatever other language(s) you know - some other languages use reference semantics by default but C++ defaults to value semantics.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data/output.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy as text instead, and format with a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you are returning a copy when you return here:

```cpp
    intClass getIC(int index)
    {
        return ics[index];
    }
```

The fix is very easy which is just to return a reference rather than a new `intClass` object.  Like so:

```cpp
    intClass& getIC(int index)
    {
        return ics[index];
    }
```